# Ruby Enterprise Edition vs Ruby 1.9.2 memory improvements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-enterprise-edition

I have a couple of rails applications running on VPS. As I have to pay extra for more ram I have been using REE.

As rails is getting ready to deprecate 1.8.7 as of Rails 4.0 I'm starting to think about making the move to 1.9.2 (which would be nice for other reasons).

However... I can't find out any information on whether the memory improvements used in REE have been migrated into 1.9.2.

Does anyone know the REE claims of a 25% reduction in memory footprint still hold true when compared against ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that many of those improvements are "not necessary in 1.9."

The long answer is to read this [blog post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/) from Phusion (the people behind Passenger and REE).

Comment: awesome. that's exactly what I was looking for... I guess ruby-1.9.3-perf here I come =)